# MySQL Order by matching rows in First Table then rest

Tags: mysql, sql

Folks, I am having a hard time coming up with a sql that will provide me with the following output:

```
ID|CITY_SLUG|BAIRRO|NEIGHBORHOOD_BAIRRO|CIDADE|UF|STATE_SLUG
4444|4444|Porto Alegre do Norte
5671|5671|Porto Alegre do Piauí
7994|7994|Porto Alegre
9919|9919|Porto Alegre do Tocantins
12538|12538|Linha Porto Alegre
12538|12538|Centro|63310|Linha Porto Alegre|RS|rs
7994|7994|Aberta dos Morros|13460|Porto Alegre|RS|rs
4444|4444|Centro|38981|Porto Alegre do Norte|MT|mt
5671|5671|Centro|39387|Porto Alegre do Piauí|PI|pi
9919|9919|Setor Central|32994|Porto Alegre do Tocantins|TO|to
4444|4444|Centro|38981|Porto Alegre do Norte|MT|mt
5671|5671|Centro|39387|Porto Alegre do Piauí|PI|pi
7994|7994|Aberta dos Morros|13460|Porto Alegre|RS|rs
```

The idea is to first list the cities then list the Neighborhoods of the matching City name, This is my sql:

```
Select 
CITY.ID, 
CITY.SLUG as CITY_SLUG,  
NEIGHBORHOOD.NAME as BAIRRO, 
NEIGHBORHOOD.SLUG AS NEIGHBORHOOD_BAIRRO, 
CITY.NAME as CIDADE,  
STATE.ABB AS UF,  
STATE.SLUG AS STATE_SLUG  
from CITY
LEFT OUTER join STATE on CITY.ID_STATE=STATE.ID
LEFT OUTER join NEIGHBORHOOD on NEIGHBORHOOD.ID_CITY = CITY.ID
WHERE (CITY.NAME LIKE '%PORTO ALE%' )
```

Comment: I think that some context on your source tables is required.

Comment: `JOIN` combines the related rows in the same row of the result. You want the neighborhoods in separate rows? You need to use `UNION` to put things in different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Barmar, first fetch the rows having matched City names, and then create a UNION with rows having Neighbourhood for matched City names. Add relevant logic to ignore the columns having NULL value:

```
Select 
CITY.ID, 
CITY.SLUG as CITY_SLUG,  
NEIGHBORHOOD.NAME as BAIRRO, 
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL
from CITY
LEFT OUTER join STATE on CITY.ID_STATE=STATE.ID
LEFT OUTER join NEIGHBORHOOD on NEIGHBORHOOD.ID_CITY = CITY.ID
WHERE (CITY.NAME LIKE '%PORTO ALE%' )
UNION
Select 
CITY.ID, 
CITY.SLUG as CITY_SLUG,  
NEIGHBORHOOD.NAME as BAIRRO, 
NEIGHBORHOOD.SLUG AS NEIGHBORHOOD_BAIRRO, 
CITY.NAME as CIDADE,  
STATE.ABB AS UF,  
STATE.SLUG AS STATE_SLUG  
from CITY
LEFT OUTER join STATE on CITY.ID_STATE=STATE.ID
LEFT OUTER join NEIGHBORHOOD on NEIGHBORHOOD.ID_CITY = CITY.ID
WHERE (CITY.NAME LIKE '%PORTO ALE%' )
```

Comment: I modified it a little bit to match the actual columns...thanks